# Why std::thread can't open a QT Dialog?

Tags: qt, c++11, stdthread

I want to open a simple QT dialog inside a std::thread, but it crashes after the dialog open success.

```
std::thread([&](){
    DialogWarning* dlg=new DialogWarning();
    dlg->setModal(true);
    dlg->exec();
    delete dlg;
}).detach();
```

What is the problem with this code?

Comment: when I delete the codes of the std::thread,it work well. So why it crash when using std::thread?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UI components can only be opened from the main thread (aka the GUI thread).

From [Threading basics | Qt 5.13](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html):

> The Qt GUI must run in this *[the main]* thread. All widgets and several related classes, for example QPixmap, don't work in secondary threads.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason that you cannot open the dialog in a different thread has been correctly mentioned by @MarkoPacak.

However, what you can do to fix the problem is to `emit` a signal in your thread to be captured by a `slot` in the main thread. Then, in your slot, you can show the dialog.